# Heroku deploying not working with Nodejs "module not found'

Tags: node.js, heroku

I run out of solutions to my problem.
I've tried to deploy my nodejs server with Heroku and for some reason (I've tried everything) I still have the same issues.
If I use the heroku run bash command and run my start script I works as a charm, but when I run heroku open then...

```
2020-12-07T23:42:24.926855+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/controllers/delivery.controller.js
2020-12-07T23:42:24.926856+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/routes/delivery.routes.js
2020-12-07T23:42:24.926856+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/app.js
2020-12-07T23:42:24.926875+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:15)
2020-12-07T23:42:24.926875+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:27)
2020-12-07T23:42:24.926876+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
2020-12-07T23:42:24.926876+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
2020-12-07T23:42:24.926876+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/models/dbServices.js:1:15)
2020-12-07T23:42:24.926877+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
2020-12-07T23:42:24.926877+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
2020-12-07T23:42:24.926877+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
2020-12-07T23:42:24.926878+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
2020-12-07T23:42:24.926878+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19) {
2020-12-07T23:42:24.926878+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2020-12-07T23:42:24.926878+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [
2020-12-07T23:42:24.926879+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/models/dbServices.js',
2020-12-07T23:42:24.926879+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/models/delivery.models.js',
2020-12-07T23:42:24.926879+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/controllers/delivery.controller.js',
2020-12-07T23:42:24.926880+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/routes/delivery.routes.js',
2020-12-07T23:42:24.926880+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/app.js'
2020-12-07T23:42:24.926880+00:00 app[web.1]: ]
2020-12-07T23:42:24.926881+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2020-12-07T23:42:25.014284+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-12-07T23:42:25.058934+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-12-07T23:42:25.823592+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=brocoliserver.herokuapp.com request_id=363aee5c-8262-4319-a958-0a07501fee51 fwd="88.125.237.207" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-12-07T23:48:28.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user emmanuelle.zenou.rogala@gmail.com
2020-12-07T23:48:45.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-12-07T23:48:45.389699+00:00 app[api]: Release v11 created by user emmanuelle.zenou.rogala@gmail.com
2020-12-07T23:48:45.389699+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 0d98c876 by user emmanuelle.zenou.rogala@gmail.com
2020-12-07T23:48:46.665684+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-12-07T23:48:49.418790+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2020-12-07T23:48:52.552335+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:818
2020-12-07T23:48:52.552366+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2020-12-07T23:48:52.552367+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2020-12-07T23:48:52.552367+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-12-07T23:48:52.552368+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'mysql'
2020-12-07T23:48:52.552368+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2020-12-07T23:48:52.552368+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/models/dbServices.js
2020-12-07T23:48:52.552369+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/models/delivery.models.js
2020-12-07T23:48:52.552369+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/controllers/delivery.controller.js
2020-12-07T23:48:52.552370+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/routes/delivery.routes.js
2020-12-07T23:48:52.552370+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/app.js
2020-12-07T23:48:52.552387+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:15)
2020-12-07T23:48:52.552388+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:27)
2020-12-07T23:48:52.552388+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
2020-12-07T23:48:52.552389+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
2020-12-07T23:48:52.552389+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/models/dbServices.js:1:15)
2020-12-07T23:48:52.552390+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
2020-12-07T23:48:52.552390+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
2020-12-07T23:48:52.552390+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
2020-12-07T23:48:52.552391+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
2020-12-07T23:48:52.552391+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19) {
2020-12-07T23:48:52.552392+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2020-12-07T23:48:52.552392+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [
2020-12-07T23:48:52.552392+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/models/dbServices.js',
2020-12-07T23:48:52.552393+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/models/delivery.models.js',
2020-12-07T23:48:52.552393+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/controllers/delivery.controller.js',
2020-12-07T23:48:52.552393+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/routes/delivery.routes.js',
2020-12-07T23:48:52.552394+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/app.js'
2020-12-07T23:48:52.552394+00:00 app[web.1]: ]
2020-12-07T23:48:52.552394+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2020-12-07T23:48:52.640097+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-12-07T23:48:52.691307+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-12-07T23:48:52.695158+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-12-07T23:48:55.954237+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2020-12-07T23:48:59.617300+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:818
2020-12-07T23:48:59.617348+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2020-12-07T23:48:59.617349+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2020-12-07T23:48:59.617349+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-12-07T23:48:59.617349+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'mysql'
2020-12-07T23:48:59.617350+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2020-12-07T23:48:59.617350+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/models/dbServices.js
2020-12-07T23:48:59.617351+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/models/delivery.models.js
2020-12-07T23:48:59.617351+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/controllers/delivery.controller.js
2020-12-07T23:48:59.617351+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/routes/delivery.routes.js
2020-12-07T23:48:59.617352+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/app.js
2020-12-07T23:48:59.617359+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:15)
2020-12-07T23:48:59.617360+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:27)
2020-12-07T23:48:59.617361+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
2020-12-07T23:48:59.617361+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
2020-12-07T23:48:59.617361+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/models/dbServices.js:1:15)
2020-12-07T23:48:59.617361+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
2020-12-07T23:48:59.617362+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
2020-12-07T23:48:59.617362+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
2020-12-07T23:48:59.617362+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
2020-12-07T23:48:59.617363+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19) {
2020-12-07T23:48:59.617363+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2020-12-07T23:48:59.617363+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [
2020-12-07T23:48:59.617364+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/models/dbServices.js',
2020-12-07T23:48:59.617364+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/models/delivery.models.js',
2020-12-07T23:48:59.617364+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/controllers/delivery.controller.js',
2020-12-07T23:48:59.617365+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/routes/delivery.routes.js',
2020-12-07T23:48:59.617365+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/app.js'
2020-12-07T23:48:59.617365+00:00 app[web.1]: ]
2020-12-07T23:48:59.617366+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2020-12-07T23:48:59.710666+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-12-07T23:48:59.780212+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-12-07T23:49:05.437113+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=brocoliserver.herokuapp.com request_id=53e2e783-b063-411e-abc7-a58a60a53b81 fwd="88.125.237.207" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-12-07T23:54:47.834773+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=brocoliserver.herokuapp.com request_id=7f99c958-d7d1-4ea6-b1ae-4cd4483af6f1 fwd="88.125.237.207" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Please can you help me fix it? I don't understand how it could work with the heroku run bash (which means my modules are ok, my port too etc...) but not with heroku open command.

Answer (score 0):

I want to die ... I was always doing  `git push heroku` because for some reason `git push heroku master` the source master was not defined ... I use `git push heroku main` and it works . I am so fustrated right now lol